# How to Change locale of Flutter Local Notifications within app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-local-notification, flutter-localizations

In my code i am changing locale language within app without changing device language but when i change language from **English** to **Arabic** Flutter local notification still display notifications as Locale (en,US) but i want those notifications to be shown in Locale (ar,SA) so is there any way to change locale of Flutter Local Notifications within app too without changing Device Language. If there is any way then please share the code. By the way for push notifications i am using FCM.